# Override link color inside some tag

Tags: html, css

I have some html page. But can't override link color in navigation panel.

```
<section>
  <div>
    <H2>Some text here</H2>
    <a href="#">Some link here</a>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="navbar-lower-container">
  <nav>    
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Articles</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</section>
```

Both css and html can be found here:
https://codepen.io/lomachx/pen/WNbLgYa

Comment: The colors appear to work for me.  Though your use of `!important` is overruling the pseudo-selectors, why are you using that?  What isn't working for you?

Comment: .nav a {
  color: yellow !important;
} with this code you give the color to the link on your navigation panel! What's your problem?

Comment: Do not use !important everywhere. It makes your code difficult to change in the future.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Yes. Thanks everyone. I didn't know that "!important" can affect selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just You need to delete the

```
!important
```

from css classes and then You can change the color from this class

```
.nav a {
  color: #690;//Blue
}
```